# Uncaught TypeErrors

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a custom modal pop-up which is based on simplemodal.js. It appeaars to work "out of the box" here, https://uat5-m.usbank.com/mobile-web/simple-modal-test1.html, but when i try to integrate it into modernizr.min.js, i get these uncaught type error messages. See here :http://uat5-m.usbank.com/mobile-web/simple-modal-test2.html

Does any one know of a way to integrate simplemodal.js, confirm.js and modernizr so that it does not break?

Thanks in advance for your help, as always.

Regards,
umbre gachoong

Comment: It appears that the class "menu_stack_1" doesn't exist. Is homeController your code? See line 1366 of your modernizr.min.js. That is the error I'm seeing when I visit your link.

Comment: Chrome won't load jQuery as you've included it from jQuery.com, which compromises the security of the page.  You might have to rehost a copy of jQuery on your domain.